# How can I adjust the length of second cell in a table?

Tags: html, html-table

[image]

How can I adjust the length of second cell in a table?
I want to reduce the length of NAME cell..
    Here is some code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Pizza Order Menu</title>
<style>

table , td, th {border:1px solid black; text-align:center; width:580px; height:30px;}
td {width:200px; height:30px; text-align:left;}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>

<tr >
<th id="head">Pizza Shop 2.0 </th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="name">Name</td> 
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you reduce the length of the lower cell, you will also reduce the width of the cell in the row above. They are in the same column. You can't have different widths for the same column. However, you could put "Name" in a `div` within the `td`, then adjust the width of the `div`. There are other options, as well. Maybe you could add more details to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `colspan="2"` to the head you can then make the bottom row smaller by adding in another table data.

I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/40fa1hsf/) for you.

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 580px;
  height: 30px;
}
td {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: left;
}
.name {
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<title>Pizza Order Menu</title>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th id="head" colspan="2">Pizza Shop 2.0</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Name</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```